# Unity's deferred rendering setting seems to be gone, or am I completly wrong?

Tags: unity-game-engine, settings

I started playing with unity with the version 5.4.

Then it was possible to change the rendering mode to "deferred" when going to the menu Project Settings -> Player.

I remember it for sure to be next to the "Color Space" option but on the Unity version 5.5 it is gone and I cant find this **global** setting anymore. :/ I know that I can set my camera to render in deferred mode but I'd like to set this globally to avoid any big render issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering Mode Settings has been moved to [Graphics Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GraphicsSettings.html) starting from *Unity* 5.5.

To access the new Settings Window, go to *Edit* -> *Project Settings* ->*Graphics*.

You can read more about the new Rendering Paths [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderingPaths.html). For more information about [Deferred shading](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderTech-DeferredShading.html) and [Forward](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderTech-ForwardRendering.html) Rendering Paths.

Comment: Thank you very much! Didnt found it somehow... :)